# Hibernate Query Cache Eviction

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

Environment: Spring 4.2.6, Hibernate 4.x, Hazelcast 3.9

We have enabled L2 Cache and Query Cache via the hibernate properties in Spring Config xml. In addition, database query log and hibernate statistics/sql trace are enabled.  The server.log clearly indicates that both query cache and L2 cache are enabled (via HZ log statements). Eviction is also configured for a high number (12 hours)

Config:

```
   <network>
   .....
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
        </tcp-ip>
   </network>

   <map name="default">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>43200</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>3600</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE">20</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>300</min-eviction-check-millis>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

When the app is started, HQL queries and JDBC times are visible in the logs as the maps start filling up.  When we then make a request to the app, part of the data is fetched from the cache and the balance data is queried from DB (visible via hibernate and db logs).  If the request is repeated within a very short interval (approx < 20 secs) the DB queries are not fired again.  However if the request is repeated after a longer duration (say around 30 secs), some of the same queries are fired again.  Repeat immediately and the same queries are not fired.

Question: Is there a way we can control the eviction / time that the query cache data is in memory? Why is the data cleared out so fast for some queries?

Comment: If you didn't configure any eviction in Hazelcast it'll most probably a config in Hibernate but I'm not a Hibernate master. Sorry.

Comment: I updated the question. Eviction is configured for 12 hours

Comment: Can you add your Hazelcast configuration?

Comment: HZ Config snippet updated,  Note that the tests are currently being performed on my laptop single node.

Comment: How big's the heap of the JVM and what's the usage? ~80%?

Comment: The mancenter indicates heap space free > 20%. While playing around with config changed the policy from heap free % to PER_NODE and the query cache looks to be working. Does that help?

Comment: I can't really answer that question. I still wonder why the values are actually thrown away. All ideas is picking in the dark right now. I would expect that something uses specific TTL values which overrides the config from XML.

Comment: Is there a way to set the amount of memory HZ can use? Then I could vary a limit and check the behavior.

Comment: Hazelcast is just a Java application, so you configure the heap size to define how much memory Hazelcast can use. Only if you use Hazelcast Enterprise HD and the HDMS (some kind of an offheap implementation) you have to configure it differently as data is not stored in the Java heap anymore.

Comment: I was not fully clear. In our app HZ runs embedded inside Spring app in Wildfly. JVM setting is for whole app in Wildfly. Can I still limit HZ or is that not possible?

Comment: You could try to configure a number of entries / entry memory usage based on the eviction. Apart from that there's no way to do this. In general there are very few use cases where we recommend embedded clusters over standalone.